# How to attach onload event for sap.ui.commons.image?

Tags: html, sapui5

I'm wondering how to attach onload event for [SAPUI5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#content/Overview.html) image

```
var image = new sap.ui.commons.Image({id: "cImage"})
```

I know that there is a way using native js or jquery onload event to do it, but my question is how can I do this using SAPUI5 events like attachPress for clicking for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching I found a method for ui5 controls called 'attachBrowserEvent' which can handle any browser event:

```
image.attachBrowserEvent('load', function(){
    alert("Image loaded");
});
```